# Nullpointer Exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am making a java game and I am getting the following error:

```
actionPerformedException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at OurGame.Ball.checkCollision(Ball.java:53)
    at OurGame.Ball.actionPerformed(Ball.java:57)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It is happening when my game checks for collision between the ball and my other object. This is my code for `Ball.java`:

```
package OurGame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ball extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int x, y, cx, cy;
    
        Image img;
        ImageIcon i;
        
        Player p;
        Board b;
        
        Timer t;
        Random r;
        
        Rectangle player, ball;
        
        
        public Ball() {
            r = new Random();
            x = 500;
            y = 190;
            cx = -1;

            
            System.out.println("New coin created: " + x + ", " +y);
            
            i = new ImageIcon("ball.png");
            img = i.getImage();
            
            t = new Timer(10,this);
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.print("actionPerformed");
            checkCollision();
            move();
        }
        
        public void checkCollision(){
            
            player = new Rectangle(p.getX(),p.getY(),10,32);
            ball = new Rectangle(getX(),getY(),8,8);
            
            if (player.intersects(ball))
            {
               // A Collision!
               // we know which enemy (e), so we can call e.DoCollision();
               b.score += 1;


               if(cx == -1) {
                   cx = 1;
               } else {
                   if(cx == 1) {
                       cx = -1;
                   }
               }
               System.out.println("Collided");
            } else {
            }
        }
        
        
        public void move() {
            System.out.print("MOVING");
            x += cx;

            
        }
        
        public void setX(int xs) {
            x = xs;
        }
        
        public void setY(int ys) {
            y = ys;
        }
        public Image getImage(){
            return img;
        }
        
        public int getX(){
            return x;
        }
        
        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }
    

}
```

The error is occurring at this piece of code:

```
player = new Rectangle(p.getX(),p.getY(),10,32);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Ball` class has a field called `p` that is of type `Player`.

But you never assign a value to that field, so it will always be `null`.

Trying to call any method on that `null` value will surely result in a `NullPointerException`.

You *either* need to ensure that every `Ball` has a `Player` assigned (ideally during construction) *or* change your code to handle the lack of a `Player` (i.e. check for `null` where appropriate).

Also, the `Rectangle` fields `player` and `ball` only seem to be used in the `checkCollision` method and therefore should be local variables declared in that method and *not* fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set value for 'p' (Player) of Ball? 'p' is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `p` hasn't been initialized.  Where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score -1):

You have a `null`. [This link](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/01/javalangnullpointerexception-how-to.html) it will explain to you what the meaning of a java `NullPointerException`.